# (WinForm C#) How do I make my mainform's Autoscroll fixed?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, autoscroll

As you can see from this video.

[My Problem's Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dhK2mliT68JCOF6K36FazVcwQZo6hFQZ/view?usp=share_link)

Whenever each listview (top and bottom ones) got focused again, the main form's scroller would move a little, which made the listview trigger a drag-drop event when I re-clicked the other listview.

For example, suppose the top listview is focused, when I click the bottom one, the main form's scroller will move a little. At the moment, the bottom listview will view that I'm dragging an item on it so it will show a message to me. Vice versa.

The drag-drop event is necessary because it's the "copy & paste" function here.

Therefore, how do I make the main form's scroller fixed when I clicked the other listview again (the main form's scroller only moves when I need to move it)?

Comment: You could just store the form's AutoScrollPosition in a field of the form class at the listview's MouseDown event.  And check that it is still the same in the ItemDrag event handler.

Comment: @HansPassant 
I added this to note the current position of the scrollbar from my Mainform:

`Point point = this.AutoScrollPosition;`

and put this code in the events which might make the mainform's scrollbar move:

`this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(point.X), Math.Abs(point.Y));`

Then it's solved now~ Thank you~!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HansPassant

1. I added this to note the current position of the scrollbar from my Mainform:

   ```
   Point point = this.AutoScrollPosition;
   ```
2. And put this code in the events which might make the mainform's scrollbar move:

   ```
   this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(point.X), Math.Abs(point.Y));
   ```
3. Then it's solved now~ Thank you~!!